# How to change the default person in the inbuilt simulator in Spark AR Studio?

Tags: spark-ar-studio

As seen in F8 developer conference, there was the option to select from 5-6 different person to be used as sample in the inbuilt simulator in Spark AR studio. Where to find the option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V78 if you are using older version it could be different(don't use them)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own videos too as long as they are in .webpm format

[Just tap on the plus sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bykkQ.jpg)